# SCNScene - Navigate inside an object in .dae file

Tags: ios, blender, scenekit, virtual-reality

I created a simple cube using [blender](http://www.blender.org/) and exported it in `dae` file format. In my app I am able to show the same object by following below steps:

1. In storyboard add an `SCNView` object to a view controller
2. Assign `.dae` file to `SCNView` via `Scene` property in its attribute inspector

The object thus presented is interactive, user can change orientations of the presented object.

I want to know if there is any way of providing functionality to user of navigation inside the presented 3D object via `SceneKit`?

Please suggest.

Comment: what do you mean by "navigation inside the cube"?

Comment: hi @mnuages I mean to be able to move inside the cube.

Comment: it seems that you've already activated the default camera control behaviour. Using this built-in "navigation" mechanism there's nothing that should prevent you from being able to move inside the cube. Are you seeing otherwise?

Comment: yeah.. I am planning to upload the sample project in a github repository, hope you will be able to help :)